# Plot the results of integrating a complicated Dirac-delta function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

```
Plot[Integrate[Sin[6.28*10^10 x]/(-x + t)
   (1 + (-0.99995*(3.33*10^-8 - 0.99995 x) + 
     22.4 Sin[1.256*10^11 x])/
    ((3.33*10^-8 - 0.99995 x)^2 + 
      7.13*10^-10 (Sin[6.28*10^10 x])^2)^0.5)*
  DiracDelta[
  x -  t + ((3.33*10^-8 - 0.99995 x)^2 + 
       7.13*10^-10*(Sin[6.28*10^10 x])^2)^(1/2)], {x,0, 0,5*10^-9}], {t, 0, 0.001}]
```

I tried evaluating the above expression, but takes forever. Am I doing it right? Should I use `NIntegrate`

---

```
Plot[f[t], {t, 0, 0.0001}]
```

Then (took~20hrs)

[image]

Could I get better plot from this?

Comment: Before try to plot the results of the integration, you should evaluate the `Integrate` expression at top-level. You will (quickly) find it does't work.

Comment: Yes I tried to evaluate Integrate at top-level, but neither work

Comment: For `{t -> 0.0005, x -> 10^-9}` the argument of `DiracDelta` has a nonzero imaginary component and the `DiracDelta` function is undefined.  Perhaps you should check your formula.

Comment: Michael E2: Nope. t->0.0001 is for plot range and x->10^-9 is for the integration range

Comment: you need to express delta in terms of the root(s) of its argument, which you need to find numerically. math.stackexchange.com if you need help with that.

Comment: @user16308 Nope. The argument to `Integrate` is of the form `f[t, x]`, `x` being the integration variable and `t` being a parameter. `Plot` substitutes numbers for `t` in the interval `0 <= t <= 0.001`; `Integrate` is over the interval `0 <= x <= 5*10^-9`. So `{t, x]} == {0.0005, 10^-9}` lies in that domain and the integrand is undefined. In fact, the integrand is undefined at `t == 0.0005` for all `x` between `0` and `5*10^-9`. Unless you have an interpretation of `DiracDelta` at a complex number? (Btw, you need to put an @ in front of my name or I don't get notified of your response.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 What do you mean by "In fact, the integrand is undefined at t == 0.0005 for all x between 0 and 5*10^-9"?

Comment: @user16308  I mean, before you just changed the function!, your integrand had a factor `DiracDelta[x - t + (x - t + ((3.33*10^-8 - 0.99995 x)^2 + 7.13*10^-10*(Sin[6.28*10^10 x])^2)^(1/2))^(1/2)]`.  Inside that, there is a term `Sqrt[-t + x + Sqrt[(3.33*10^-8 - 0.99995 x)^2 + 7.13*10^-10 Sin[6.28*10^10 x]^2]]`.  When you substitute `t -> 0.0005` and `Minimize`/`Maximize` the term, you see that the range of the expression `-t + x + Sqrt[(3.33*10^-8 - 0.99995 x)^2 + 7.13*10^-10 Sin[6.28*10^10 x]^2]` inside the `1/2` power was `-0.000499967` to `-0.000473298` and the 1/2 pwer would be imaginary...

Comment: ...So the `DiracDelta` would have an argument that complex with a nonzero imaginary part.  AFAIK, the delta function is undefined for nonreal arguments.  I thought you might know of such a definition.  But now you have changed the formula to eliminate the problem, without indicating that you have done so -- that seems rather DISHONEST!

Comment: But at least now the problem can be solved.

Comment: @MichaelE2  Sorry If I made feel you bad, but I didn't understand your comments at all, had assumed some typos. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user16308  No problem.  It *seemed* sneaky - because your edit removed the problem I was trying to point out.  See if george's answer does what you want.

Comment: @MichaelE2 But When I try to paste the formula in mathematica, doesn't work. Should I type again???

Comment: @user16308 You need to replace george's `...` with your function.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I can't paste even other parts like f[t_ ~~~~. Can't do any single letter...

Answer (score 2):

with the fix, `Integrate` works, the trick is you need to `Integrate` for numerical values of t:  (Primarily I'm posting this because i was surprised it works )

```
 f[t_?NumericQ] := f[t] =   Integrate[ ..., {x, 0, 5*10^-9}]
```

I'm using `ListPlot` on a small table here so I can control exactly the points that get calculated -- This should work with `Plot` but I expect it might take hours. (5-10 minutes as is)

```
 ListPlot[Table[ {t, f[t]} , {t, 0, 2/100000, 1/1000000}], 
      Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

note I'm not at all confident this is accurate.. the argument of your `DiracDelta` has a few dozen roots for each `t`.

### simpler example

To see how this works here is a cleaner example of the same form:

```
 g[x_] = x^3;
 f[x_] = x Cos[x + Pi/4];
 Integrate[g[x]  DiracDelta[f[x] ] , {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi }]
```

> -2 Pi^2

the argument to `DiracDelta` , `f[x]` has five roots in the integration domain:

```
 fxroots = {  -7 Pi/4  , -3 Pi/4, 0 , Pi/4  , 5 Pi/4 };
```

after finding the roots the integral is reduced to the sum of the following  values at the roots:

```
 g[x]/Abs[f'[x]] /. x -> # & /@ fxroots
```

> {-((49 Pi^2)/16), -((9 Pi^2)/16), 0, Pi^2/16, (
>    25 Pi^2)/16}

which totals to the value obtained by `Integrate`

```
Total@%
```

> -2 Pi^2

For the example in he question `f[x]` is highly oscillatory with ~20 roots that need to be numerically determined for each `t`, which is why its so slow..

Comment: I got 199 roots at some point.  I suppose one needs to worry about multiple roots, too....

Comment: i did too, somewhere in the edit trail he threw in a factor of 10  ..

Comment: Isn't it the case that if a multiple root appears inside `DiracDelta` there's a problem.  Consider `Integrate[x DiracDelta[(x - 3)^2], {x, 0, 4}]`.  If the argument of `DiracDelta` is written `f[x] - t`, it seems there are many values of `t`, one for every minimum of `f[x]`, that give such a double root.  I think an accurate graph will take some effort to obtain.

Comment: @MichaelE2 the integral blows up at the repeated root because the first derivative is zero.